# Interpret a string as it refers to an in program variable. Geant4 units

Tags: c++, string, eval

So, I understand that this is not something built into the language (i.e. there is no eval() method in c++). I also understand that it is very difficult to associate the contents of a string input at runtime with a variable name from the program, since most of that info goes away. Nevertheless...

I am trying to write a little class to allow users in my research group to add materials and material properties into a database file and call those materials up with one command so that material construction is easy in Geant4. Unfortunately, Geant4 uses a header file to define actual variables for these units such as cm3, mm, MeV, and kg to convert units into the internal Geant4 system of units. I don't believe there is any kind of map that links these to their corresponding strings. The fact of the matter is, Geant4 is for physics modelling, and there are a butt ton of units. There is no real way I can map them all, either, since Geant4 is expandable and some new physics code may come along that wants a new unit I don't know about.

What I would like to do is get the string that describes the unit from the text file and somehow match that to the actual variable of the same name so I can perform the conversion. Is there any way to hack and slash this out, or is it totally impossible (or totally nearly impossible)?

Of course I could make people convert to the internal units for all of their database entries, but that could quickly get ugly and be a large source of hard to track down error (15 places before the decimal looks a lot like 14).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer, partly because I've never used (or heard of before now) Geant4, and partly because it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do: are you making a C++ library for your colleagues to use directly? Or are you making some kind of tool that your colleagues can use without touching C++ themselves?

Still, I'll try to answer as best I can.

Fundamentally, if you want to take textual input at runtime and interpret named units, then you need a mapping table from unit names to definitions (whatever internal form those definitions take). There isn't really any way around that.

However, you don't necessarily need to create that mapping table by hand. The information must be present in the Geant4 header file that defines the units, so you could write a (hack and slash, as you put it) tool to read that header file and generate code for a mapping table.

As for supporting new units in the future, it may be possible but I don't really understand enough about your problem to suggest a particular approach.

I'll go out on a limb a little here though. A quick google search for Geant4, and an extremely cursory search through the first source code I found leads me to two relevant files: [SystemOfUnits.h](http://proj-clhep.web.cern.ch/proj-clhep/doxygen/html/SystemOfUnits_8h.html), and [G4UnitsTable.hh](http://www-geant4.kek.jp/lxr/source/global/management/include/G4UnitsTable.hh).

I note that [2](http://www-geant4.kek.jp/lxr/source/global/management/include/G4UnitsTable.hh) provides exactly the name-to-definition mapping that you might want, but I'm unclear as to how it relates to the rest of the system and therefore whether it's relevant.

If [1](http://proj-clhep.web.cern.ch/proj-clhep/doxygen/html/SystemOfUnits_8h.html) is the relevant header, then clearly the definitions of the units is about the simplest possible: that is, scaling factors to base units. If this is the case, then there's no particular reason why your material database file shouldn't also contain unit definitions of a similar sort (that is, load your mapping table from the same place that you load the material definitions), which would allow your colleagues to add new units as necessary.

There is one final possibility I might mention, which is that while counting decimal digits is, I agree, extremely prone to error, if you allow values to be represented in scientific notation then much of that problem goes away. So, possibly the simplest solution is to tell your colleagues to use the basic Geant4 units, and if they want to specify a value of, say, 5 km, they should specify it as 5e6 (since the Geant4 basic unit for length is the millimetre, according to [1](http://proj-clhep.web.cern.ch/proj-clhep/doxygen/html/SystemOfUnits_8h.html)).

Comment: I didn't think about putting basic units definitions in the database file and creating a units table. That's a really good idea. Thanks!